# How to implement efficient wifi communication between an Android device and a PC?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, c++-cli

First of all, my question is not about setting the wifi hot spot. I do this easily using `netsh`. My question is rather about performing communications socket-to-socket between the PC and the device.

The android device acts as the server: I use a thread where a `ServerSocket` waits for a connection (`accept()`) then returns a `Socket`. It then starts a second thread where I access the streams through an `InputStreamReader` and a `PrintWriter`. I read the characters and when it's done I send the answer back. I keep the `Socket` open as long as I have to keep the communication up.

The PC is programmed in C++/CLI (.NET) and acts as the client. (Actually, the Android device is the wifi client of the PC hot spot but with my program, it is the inverse: the computer has to make requests to the device; not the opposite.) So I create a `Socket` (*SocketType=Stream, ProtocolType=Tcp*, maybe I'm wrong doing this). Then I connect it. The actual connection works: but It can take up to few seconds. Any way, if I have to do it one or two times, it is not a problem. Then I send the request using `Send()` and get the answer using `Receive()`.

Now, to test the system, I use PuTTY. I connect correctly and the data are sent and received correctly. The problem is that there is a tremendous delay. Let's see an example:

o Send: CONNECT

wait up to 5 seconds...

o Receive: OK

I would have expected it to be ~instantaneous. I used the Eclipse debugger to see if the delay occurs in the PC-to-Device part of the communication or in the Device-to-PC part. It seems that it takes about as much time in both directions.

1. Is it correct to use a Stream Socket with Tcp protocol (PC side?)
2. Are there some settings somewhere in the sockets or deeper in Android that I could fine tune to make such data exchanges faster?

I can of course give you more info but I don't know what is relevant and what is not. Feel free to ask for more details.

Thanks for the help you can give me!

Comment: Hmm.. 5 seconds to open a TCP connection over wireless network, (with it's humungously complex airside protocols and hardware generating considerable latency and so really slowing up the 3-way handshake), does not seem unreasonable.   It does seem rather long for a data exchange, however.  I wonder if this effect is some nagle-like effect?  Wireless networks tend to get optimised to download web pages and other such streams of large buffers and really don't like ping-pong protocols that only transfer small amounts of data.

Comment: @MartinJames That is why I'm looking for buffer size or auto flushing tweaking...

Comment: @MartinJames 5 seconds was due to an issue with the tablet I was working with. I tried other devices and everything is fine. Thanks.